Same side multiple misfire jeep liberty 3.7 troubleshoot
All three cylinders misfire at the same time on the same side. What’s the reasoning?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked your fuses? Is it electrical or fuel related? What are the misfire codes?
